# Suppress "nothing to be done for 'all' "

Tags: shell, makefile

I am writing a short shell script which calls 'make all'. It's not critical, but is there a way I can suppress the message saying 'nothing to be done for all' if that is the case? I am hoping to find a flag for make which suppresses this (not sure there is one), but an additional line or 2 of code would work too.

FYI I'm using bash.

Edit: to be more clear, I only want to suppess messages that therer is nothing to be done. Otherwise, I want to display the output.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can make "all" a PHONY target (if it isn't already) which has the real target as a prerequisite, and does something inconspicuous:

```
.PHONY: all

all: realTarget
    @echo > /dev/null
```

Comment: Rather than echo, you can probably just do @: for a no-op

Comment: @William Pursell: by golly, you're right. I never knew `:` was a shell no-op... or that I'd ever have a use for such a thing.

Comment: I like this sneaky approach. The warning goes away because `all` now has something to do, but what it does is nothing. Another option to `echo` is to make the action be `@true` which should print nothing and silently succeed.

Comment: This breaks "make -q" because make always thinks there's work to be done

Comment: this solution adds ~1 sec delay at least in MinGW

Answer (score 14):

I would like to improve on the previous solution, just to make it a little bit more efficient...:)

```
.PHONY: all
all: realTarget
        @:
```

@true would also work but is a little slower than @: (I've done some performance tests). In any case both are quite faster than "echo > /dev/null"...

Answer (score 1):

The flag `-s` silences make: `make -s all`

**EDIT:** I originally answered that the flag `-q` silenced make. It works for me, although the manpage specifies `-s, --silent, --quiet` as the valid flags.

Comment: W Tenney, for me this is `-s`, `--silent` or `--quiet`

Comment: I should have been more clear. I only want to suppress the case where the files are up to date. Otherwise I want to show the output.

Comment: I saw someone else answered and suggested `make all | grep -v "Nothing to be done for"` but it seems they deleted that answer.

Answer (score 1):

The grep solution:

```
{ make all 2>&1 1>&3 | grep -v 'No rule to make target `all' >&2; } 3>&1
```

The construct `2>&1 1>&3` sends make's stdout to fd 3 and make's stderr to stdout.  grep then reads from the previous command's stdout, removes the offending line and sends its stdout to stderr.  Finally, fd 3 is returned to stdout.

---

2022-11-17, A response to @Pryftan's comment:

Ignoring the minor error that I used the wrong text.

Lets create a function that outputs some stuff

```bash
make() {
    echo "this is stdout"
    echo "this is stderr" >&2
    printf 'oops, No rule to make target `%s`, not at all' "$1" >&2
}
```

Testing my solution:

```bash
$ { make foobar 2>&1 1>&3 | grep -v 'No rule to make target `all' >&2; } 3>&1
this is stdout
this is stderr
oops, No rule to make target `foobar`, not at all

$ { make all 2>&1 1>&3 | grep -v 'No rule to make target `all' >&2; } 3>&1
this is stdout
this is stderr
```

Looks good so far.

What about without the braces?

```bash
$ make all 2>&1 1>&3 | grep -v 'No rule to make target `all' >&2 3>&1
bash: 3: Bad file descriptor
```

In this case, we'd need to explicitly create fd 3

```bash
$ exec 3>&1; make all 2>&1 1>&3 | grep -v 'No rule to make target `all' >&2 3>&1
this is stdout
this is stderr
```

What is it about the braces? I think it's delaying evaluation of the contents, and that allows the *trailing* `3>&1` to be processed *first*. And that makes the inner `1>&3` valid.

Comment: Is all that really necessary? What different from just doing the grep -v?

Comment: First of all, on my make anyway, that message goes to stderr, so at least you have to redirect stderr for grep to have any effect.  Next, you wanted the rest of make's output untouched, so I didn't want to mix stderr with stdout.  Lastly, it's a learning exercise for me too.

Comment: @glennjackman There are a number of things wrong here. First you're filtering out the wrong text. This isn't a matter of there not being a rule 'all'. Second is the FDs start from 0 - the `{}` masks the problem that fd 3 is invalid. Try removing them and you'll see what I mean. Even if you change the filter to use the correct text it won't work right for those reasons (or maybe other reasons). And you're right - that message does go to stderr but stderr is 2 and 3 is not defined (well maybe some shells have it? Not sure).

Comment: ...even so I'm voted you up for the effort and for wanting to learn as well. But @sas4740 is correct and the `grep -v` would be the right way to go about it if you're going to use grep for this task.

Comment: I have to say, I was taken aback by your comments. I spent a lot of time pondering the "fd 3 is invalid" comment and working out a justification for my (correct) answer. IMO the fact that the grep pattern isn't exactly right is trivial. I do object to "maybe other reasons" -- if you can't enumerate errors, please don't suggest they exist. This site requires more precision.