# Remove target from MAKECMDGOALS?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following in my makefile. Its a `GNUmakefile`, so the additional make features are supported:

```make
# Undefined Behavior Sanitzier (Clang and G++)
ifeq ($(findstring ubsan,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),ubsan)
CXXFLAGS += -fsanitize=undefined
MAKECMDGOALS := $(subst ubsan,,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
endif # UBsan
```

Running it results in:

```sh
make ubsan
make: *** No rule to make target 'ubsan'. Stop.
```

I know the code path is being executed (by introducing an error in the block). How do I remove the target from the command goals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do what you want here as far as I know.

You can modify the variable value and you will see the changes if you check the value yourself but modifying the value of `MAKECMDGOALS` will not affect make in any way.

If you look at [Appendix A Quick Reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Quick-Reference) in the GNU Make Manual you will see that it says:

> MAKECMDGOALS
>
> The targets given to make on the command line. Setting this variable has no effect on the operation of make.
>
> See [Arguments to Specify the Goals](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Goals).

The closest you could get to what you are trying to do here, I think, would be to re-execute make on the `Makefile` (or whatever) manually.

That being said this sort of thing is probably better done as variables instead of targets.

```
$ cat Makefile
$(info $(origin UBSAN))
$ make
undefined
$ make UBSAN=
command line
```

So something like this.

```
# Undefined Behavior Sanitzier (Clang and G++)
ifneq (undefined,$(origin UBSAN))
CXXFLAGS += -fsanitize=undefined
endif # UBsan
```

Comment: Its part of the Crypto++ project. We decided to add `ubsan` and `asan` as first class targets (with the `CXXFLAGS` modifications): [Added targets for UBsan and Asan](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/04429b291d711655ba4803b76ad4fe2d7bc3ad55). It seemed easier than trying to pound a square peg into a round hole. (We even though about the environmental variable trick. But we did not want to `set`/`unset` them because it would get in the way of laziness).

Comment: If you use a variable name that is custom to your project (`CRYPTOXX_UBSAN=` or `CRYPTOXX_SAN=ubsan`, etc.) you don't really need to unset the variable anywhere if you only use it in the toplevel makefile to add/etc. to `CXXFLAGS` but *shrug*.

Comment: **`You cannot do what you want here as far as I know.`** I managed to do it, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58360632/4934640

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Based on my recent answer to this other question [Force Makefile to execute script after building any target (just before exiting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582006/force-makefile-to-execute-script-after-building-any-target-just-before-exiting), it was very easy to do what you would like.

This has only a drawback, you will lose any command-line arguments you pass directly to make as `make all --silent`. However, you can look into the question: [How to detect if the makefile `--silent/--quiet` command line option was set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58367235/how-to-detect-if-the-makefile-silent-quiet-command-line-option), and recapture the command-line arguments you would like to repass to the second make call command on `make -f ${MAKEFILE_JUSTNAME} ${MAKECMDGOALS}`.

```bash
ECHOCMD:=/bin/echo -e
SHELL := /bin/bash


ifeq (${IS_MAKEFILE_RUNNING_TARGETS},)

MAKEFILE_JUSTNAME := $(firstword ${MAKEFILE_LIST})

# UBsan
ifeq ($(findstring ubsan,${MAKECMDGOALS}),ubsan)
    MAKECMDGOALS := $(subst ubsan,,${MAKECMDGOALS})
    USELESS := $(eval export IS_UBSAN_CXXFLAGS_SET=1)
endif

define DEFAULTTARGET :=
    printf 'Calling "%s" "%s"\n\n' "${MAKEFILE_JUSTNAME}" "${MAKECMDGOALS}"
    make -f ${MAKEFILE_JUSTNAME} ${MAKECMDGOALS}

    printf '\n'
    printf 'Running something after all rules finished\n'
endef

%:
    @:
#   printf 'IS_MAKEFILE_RUNNING_TARGETS="%s"\n' "${IS_MAKEFILE_RUNNING_TARGETS}"
    $(if ${IS_MAKEFILE_RUNNING_TARGETS},,${DEFAULTTARGET})
    $(eval export IS_MAKEFILE_RUNNING_TARGETS=1)

all:
    @:
#   printf 'IS_MAKEFILE_RUNNING_TARGETS="%s"\n' "${IS_MAKEFILE_RUNNING_TARGETS}"
    $(if ${IS_MAKEFILE_RUNNING_TARGETS},,${DEFAULTTARGET})
    $(eval export IS_MAKEFILE_RUNNING_TARGETS=1)
```

```bash
else

# UBsan
ifneq (${IS_UBSAN_CXXFLAGS_SET},)
    CXXFLAGS += -fsanitize=undefined
endif

all:
    printf 'Calling my all rule, CXXFLAGS="%s"\n' "${CXXFLAGS}"

foo:
    printf 'Calling my foo rule, CXXFLAGS="%s"\n' "${CXXFLAGS}"

bar:
    printf 'Calling my bar rule, CXXFLAGS="%s"\n' "${CXXFLAGS}"

xyzzy:
    printf 'Calling my xyzzy rule, CXXFLAGS="%s"\n' "${CXXFLAGS}"


endif
```

---

Usage examples:

1. **`make`**

   ```
   printf 'Calling "%s" "%s"\n\n' "Makefile" ""
   Calling "Makefile" ""

   make -f Makefile
   make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/d/User/Downloads'
   printf 'Calling my all rule, CXXFLAGS="%s"\n' ""
   Calling my all rule, CXXFLAGS=""
   make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/d/User/Downloads'
   printf '\n'

   printf 'Running something after all rules finished\n'
   Running something after all rules finished
   ```
2. **`make foo bar`**

   ```
   printf 'Calling "%s" "%s"\n\n' "Makefile" "foo bar"
   Calling "Makefile" "foo bar"

   make -f Makefile foo bar
   make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/d/User/Downloads'
   printf 'Calling my foo rule, CXXFLAGS="%s"\n' ""
   Calling my foo rule, CXXFLAGS=""
   printf 'Calling my bar rule, CXXFLAGS="%s"\n' ""
   Calling my bar rule, CXXFLAGS=""
   make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/d/User/Downloads'
   printf '\n'

   printf 'Running something after all rules finished\n'
   Running something after all rules finished
   ```
3. **`make foo bar ubsan`**

   ```
   printf 'Calling "%s" "%s"\n\n' "Makefile" "foo bar "
   Calling "Makefile" "foo bar "

   make -f Makefile foo bar
   make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/d/User/Downloads'
   printf 'Calling my foo rule, CXXFLAGS="%s"\n' "-fsanitize=undefined"
   Calling my foo rule, CXXFLAGS="-fsanitize=undefined"
   printf 'Calling my bar rule, CXXFLAGS="%s"\n' "-fsanitize=undefined"
   Calling my bar rule, CXXFLAGS="-fsanitize=undefined"
   make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/d/User/Downloads'
   printf '\n'

   printf 'Running something after all rules finished\n'
   Running something after all rules finished
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following pattern to pass parameters around, it has its limitations (only [a-z,0-9] characters) but can become quite handy:

```
ifeq (console,$(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS)))
  CONSOLE_ARGS := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(MAKECMDGOALS))
  $(eval $(CONSOLE_ARGS):;@:)
endif
console::
    run-some-command $(CONSOLE_ARGS)
```

For your case the following works:

```
# Undefined Behavior Sanitzier (Clang and G++)
ifeq (ubsan,$(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS)))
  CXXFLAGS += -fsanitize=undefined
  $(eval $(CONSOLE_ARGS):;@:)
endif # UBsan
```