# Makefile match any target / task

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I want to write a makefile that can be run with any task and just echo all the task names.
Is there any way to do this?

Like:

```
%.%: 
    echo "$@"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "all the task names"?

Comment: @200_success: Q title specifies `target / task`. Good luck to all.

Comment: But in the general case, not all targets can be known.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your make is GNU make or alike, use the following Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all

%:
       @echo "Here I am! $@"
```

See the result:

```
> make first
Here I am! first
> make second
Here I am! second
> make first second
Here I am! first
Here I am! second
```