# How do I get a makefile function to stop the current target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a function in a makefile that I want to stop the entire make run if a file doesn't exist, or at least the target it is executed from:

```
vaultfile = ./vault

$(shell test -f $(1) || exit 1)

define get_token
$(shell test -f $1 && cat $1 || exit 2)
endef

a: token = $(call get_token,$(vaultfile),tokenname)
a:
        echo ==== $(token)
.PHONY=a
```

The above doesn't work, silently failing when the file is missing

```
$ rm vault
$ make
echo ==== 
====
$ echo f > vault
$ make
echo ==== f
==== f
```

I want this to be in the function, because most targets do not call the function (which obviously does more IRL).

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

First a few things:

```
.PHONY=a
```

doesn't do anything: the variable `.PHONY` is not special to make.  To declare a target phony you need to list it as a prerequisite of the `.PHONY` pseudo target:

```
.PHONY: a
```

Second, this line:

```
$(shell test -f $(1) || exit 1)
```

doesn't do anything: the make variable `$(1)` is not set here so the `test` always fails, but it doesn't matter because the exit code is ignored, see below.

The exit code from the make `shell` function won't cause make to fail, it's ignored.  To cause make to think that a recipe failed you have to get the command line itself to exit with a non-zero value.

A good rule of thumb is, if you find yourself using the make `shell` function inside a recipe, you're doing something wrong and you aren't understanding how make expands variables and functions.  A recipe is already going to be passed to a shell, so you don't need to use the `shell` function at all.

Let's look at what your recipe will be after the first step of expansion, for the `token` variable:

```
    echo ==== $(call get_token,$(vaultfile),tokenname)
```

Now after the `call` function is expanded (note that the second argument to the function, `tokenname`, is completely ignored) you get:

```
    echo ==== $(shell test -f ./vault && cat ./vault || exit 2)
```

Now make expands the shell function which invokes a shell to run the command and replace the expansion with the output... but the exit code is ignored.  Let's say that `./vault` doesn't exist: then this shell command outputs nothing, and make runs this rule:

```
    echo ====
```

The best way to stop an entire make run is using the `error` function.  You can use make functions to do all the work, like this:

```
vaultfile = ./vault

get_token = $(if $(wildcard $1),`cat $1`,$(error File $1 does not exist))

a: token = $(call get_token,$(vaultfile),tokenname)
a:
        echo ==== $(token)
```

Let's look at what the results of the `call` expansion will be now:

```
    echo ==== $(if $(wildcard ,/vault),`cat ./vault`,$(error File ./vault does not exist))
```

Now make evaluates the `if` function and the condition is the `wildcard` function which will expand to `./vault` if it exists, and the empty string if not.  The `if` function treats a non-empty string as "true" and an empty string as "false", so if the file exists it will expand to:

```
    echo ==== `cat ./vault`
```

If the file doesn't exist it will run the `error` function which stops make immediately, printing that error message.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you [MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939557/madscientist)!

The simplified version of what I ended up with is: (formatted for easier readability)

```
vaultfile = ./vault

define get_token
$(shell \
$(if $(wildcard $1), \
echo "Decoded $1" \
, \
$(error File $1 does not exist)
)
)
endef

a: token = $(call get_token,$(vaultfile))
a:
        echo ==== $(token)
```