# Can I make a makefile abort outside of a rule?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

At the top of my Makefile, before any of the rules, I have the following:

```
ifeq ($(ENVIRONMENT),LOCAL)
    TARGET := local_target
else
    TARGET := hello
endif
```

If the `ENVIRONMENT` environment variable is not set, or is set to a value other than `LOCAL`, instead of setting `TARGET` to `hello`, I want the makefile to halt and exit with -1.

Can I do that?? When I change `TARGET := hello` to `exit -1`, I get the following error:

```
Makefile:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

How can I make this work??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exit` is a shell command, so you could use the [*shell assignment* operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html) (i.e.: `!=`) inside the Makefile to call `exit`:

```
TARGET != exit -1
```

This would be actually equivalent to:

```
TARGET := $(shell exit -1)
```

Note again that this calls a shell that in turns runs the shell's `exit` built-in, i.e.: it does not exit `make`. The typical approach for exiting while processing a makefile is to call GNU Make's `error` built-in function instead:

```
$(error Error-message-here)
```

Putting everything together:

```
ifeq ($(ENVIRONMENT),LOCAL)
 TARGET := local_target
else # indent with spaces, not a tab
 $(error ENVIRONMENT not set to LOCAL)
endif
```

Comment: Tip: do not put a tab before `$(error .....)`, otherwise make will complain that `recipe commences before first target`. Either do not indent at all or indent with spaces.

Comment: @harmic Thank you very much. I guess indenting `$(error ...)` with a single space as it is in the current edit, will discourage a reader from using a tab. For consistency, I've kept the same indentation in the variable assignment, even though it does not suffer from that problem.