# How to print text in a makefile outside a target?

Tags: debugging, makefile, printf

For example, I am trying to test whether this works in my makefile preamble:

```latex
ifneq (,$(shell latexmk --version 2>/dev/null))
    echo Works
else
    echo Does not Works
endif

all:
    do things...
```

Which does the error:

```
*** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.
```

Then, how to prints things outside rules?

Makefile does not allow commands outside rules, or outside `result:=$(shell ...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GNU Make there are `$(info ...)`, `$(warning ...)` and `$(error ...)` built-in functions. Note that syntactically they are text substitutions, yet their return value is always an empty string (except `$(error ...)` which never returns), as it's with `$(eval ...)` etc. So they could be used almost everywhere.

Yet another option is `$(file >/dev/stdout,...)` (under Windows use "con").

Answer (score 0):

After I found this question, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464754/how-to-see-from-which-file-descriptor-output-is-coming

I think this kinda works:

```
ifneq (,$(shell latexmk --version 2>/dev/null))
    useless := $(shell echo Works 1>&2)
else
    useless := $(shell echo Does not Works 1>&2)
    useless := $(error exiting...)
endif

all:
    echo Hey sister, do you still believe in love I wonder...
```

Bonus:

1. [Can I make a makefile abort outside of a rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040212/can-i-make-a-makefile-abort-outside-of-a-rule)