# Makefile set global variable in target body

Tags: makefile

I want to set a Global variable through a recipe then reference that variable in another **independent** recipe

The below code is an example code that sets the variable within the recipe but the variable stays with the initial value if referenced outside the recipe

```
ACTIVE = a

switch:
ifeq ($(ACTIVE),b)
    ACTIVE=$(shell echo 'a')
else
    ACTIVE=$(shell echo 'b')
endif

print:
    $(info acitve = $(ACTIVE))
```

I know there are ways to broadcast the value of a target-specific variable to dependent targets, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$(eval ...)` for this, although it's almost always a bad idea.  I have to assume that your real situation is much more complicated because there are many better ways to accomplish what you've actually provided in the sample makefile.

```
switch:
        $(eval ACTIVE=$(if $(filter-out a,$(ACTIVE)),a,b))
```

Comment: the eval function works within the scope of the recipe. Upon running `make print` the values is still `a`

Comment: How are you invoking make?  If you don't run the `switch` target then `ACTIVE` won't be reset.  `eval` modifies the global state of make, so after the `switch` target runs the global value of `ACTIVE` will be different everywhere.

Comment: `make switch` then `make print` prints `a` still

Comment: but `make switch print` does the job

Comment: Well sure: running `make switch` changes the value of the `ACTIVE` variable for that invocation of `make`.  Once it exits, everything that that invocation of make knew is gone.  When you start `make` again, it has gone back to the default.  If you want the change to persist across _invocations of make_, not just between targets within a single invocation of make, that's an entirely different thing than your question asked about.  To do that, you'll have to persist the "current" value of `ACTIVE` in the filesystem so that the next invocation of `make` can retrieve it.

Comment: Doing that is simple enough, of course... you just need to put the value in a file.